# Bigquery navigation function calculate id

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm new to bigquery and I'm having trouble using bigquery's navigation functions.
I don't understand how these functions work.

I have a table that has this structure:

| Event_id | created_ts |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 12:00:00 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 12:01:00 |
| 3 | 2020-01-01 12:05:00 |
| 4 | 2020-01-01 12:06:00 |

And I would like to calculate the session id which changes after more than one minute of inactivity.

| Session_id | created_ts |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 12:00:00 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 12:01:00 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 12:05:00 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 12:06:00 |

Here is the SQL code I started writing:

```
select event_id, 
    created_ts, 
    EXTRACT(minute FROM created_ts) as minute,
    date_diff(date(created_ts),coalesce(date(lag(created_ts - minute) over(partition by event_id order by event_id)), date(created_ts)),
) session_id
from table1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first compare the minutes  of the created datetime and see which is bigger than 1, and then filter oiz all unwanted rows

```
WITH CTE AS (
select event_id, 
    created_ts, 
CASE WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF( coalesce(date(lag(created_ts - minute) over(partition by event_id order by event_id)), date(created_ts)),date(created_ts), MINUTE) > 1 then 1 ELSE 0 END bg
from table1)
SELECT event_id, 
    created_ts
FROM CTE WHERE bg = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I had trouble understanding the syntax of subqueries in big query for the navigation functions.
I tried and it works.

Answer (score 2):

This is an other way to do it :

```
with table1 as (
  select 1 as  event_id,    '2020-01-01 12:00:00' created_ts
  union all select 2 ,  '2020-01-01 12:01:00' 
  union all select 3 ,  '2020-01-01 12:05:00' 
  union all select 4 ,  '2020-01-01 12:06:00'
  union all select 7 ,  '2020-01-01 12:10:00'
  union all select 8 ,  '2020-01-01 12:11:00'
),
CTE AS (
  SELECT *,
        CASE WHEN COALESCE(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(DATETIME(created_ts), DATETIME(LAG(created_ts) OVER(order by event_id)), MINUTE), 0) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as date_diff
  FROM table1
)
SELECT created_ts, sum(date_diff) OVER (ORDER BY event_id)+1 as Session_id
FROM CTE
```

Result :

[image]